# Working as a Family

Tags: word, knowledge, word-search

Within this Boggle grid are the names of the members of a family. The unused letters will reveal the name of the original head honcho.

```
BEVIIL  
RDRPIL  
OWENOG  
PNAXTU  
TKCELS  
ESOOAM
```

To make a word in Boggle, connect at least three letters horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, without using the same letter (e.g. the bottom left "E") twice.

Markdown transcription:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | E | V | I | I | L |
| R | D | R | P | I | L |
| O | W | E | N | O | G |
| P | N | A | X | T | U |
| T | K | C | E | L | S |
| E | S | O | O | A | M |

Comment: Would you mind an edit converting the code-formatted grid of letters to a Markdown table?

Comment: @bobble I thought about doing that but thought it would make it less clear, due to the letters being farther apart - should I add a Markdown table as well, or just convert it?

Comment: Adding a Markdown transcription, while leaving the code grid, probably couldn't hurt

Comment: @bobble IMO there is no need to add markdown to every single post you see. I understand this is your preference, but I fear it does not always _help_.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I suffer from diplopia and visual impairments, and often use screen reading to parse posts. On these occasions, I literally cannot read a table unless it is in Markdown, so a lot of posts become completely inaccessible to me. Bobble's conversion work is a godsend. Please try to remember not every site user is visual.

Comment: @Sciborg I remember reading in a meta post that Markdown is preferred for e-readers and figured the code grid would suffice, but didn't realize it impacted accessibility! My bad :/

Comment: @samm82 No worries! <3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 'family' here comprises:

> Programs and services offered by **Microsoft** (and which are commonly used in the **work**place - satisfying the title).

The members present in the grid are:

> **PowerPoint**, **Word**, **Excel**, **Teams**, **Outlook**, **OneNote**, and **OneDrive** - 7 in total.

Like so:

> [image: Solved Boggle grids]

And the unused letters spell out:

> **BILL GATES** - the co-founder ('original head honcho') of Microsoft!

Comment: The words chosen are rot13([gur pber Zvpebfbsg Bssvpr cebqhpgf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/products-apps-services)), which was the intended title hint, but yours still works! :)